# Sending complex arguments to a java program

Tags: java

I need to supply a binary license file to a java program.  What is the best way to do this?  The data will change all the time so I don't want to have to write a file and then read it back every time.

The Data is coming from a PHP page

Comment: from what will you supply the file to the java program? please explain more clear: "will change all the time".

Comment: Is handing a file to a program a complex argument? If you need to change it often, just cache the previous license data, and check the file access time to determine if you need to update or not.

Comment: The data comes from a PHP page...sorry

Comment: How is this data being passed to the Java program?  Arguments sent to a Java program appear as the main method's `String[]` array parameter.  However, Java also has access to the standard in stream as `System.in`

Comment: Actually I have not yet made the PHP page yet so this is flexible.  I will be passing a 'license file (binary)' as well as up to 10 different String attributes

Comment: I will be using the php exec() command which acts just like your were typing on the command line

Comment: You should update your question instead of posting extra infos as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will be using the php exec() command
>   which acts just like your were typing
>   on the command line

In your Java class, you'll have a method named main that look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //If this is just a single binary string, args[0] will contain the license.
}
```

If you send the license as the first argument, `args[0]` will be your incoming license.

Now, having said that, you may want to base64 encode the license before sending it.  This will make sure the license file is not affected by character sets as it is transmitted.

PHP has the function [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) for this purpose.

Java strangely does not have Base64 decoding built-in (not officially anyway).  [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) includes a decoder, though.

Again, assuming the license is the first thing passed in:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class GiveMeANameHere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base64 decoder = new Base64();
        byte[] license = decoder.decode(args[0]);

        // Do whatever you need to with the license.
        // Other strings passed in will appear as elements in args array
    }
}
```

Not that the Java code will need to be passed the Apache Commons Codec jar as it's classpath, using either `-cp path/to/commons-codec-1.4.jar` or if you package your program as a jar, in its manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Save the URL of the license file in user preferences (java.util.prefs).  If the user preferences is new or the URL and/or its contents are no longer valid, then prompt the user for a new URL (and save it back into the preferences).  You can then get the contents of the URL view java.net.URL.openStream() - works just as well for files or web addresses.

Answer (score 0):

what about handing over the path to the file?
OK
You could use something like "interprocesscommunication"
- Remote Method Invocation (RMI)
http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/rmi/
- Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)
http://www.soaprpc.com/software/
http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxm/
http://ws.apache.org/soap/features.html

Comment: it is not a file, it is data being passed from a PHP page

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to read an `InputStream` coming directly via HTTP.  If you end up going a file upload route, [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) has done a lot of your work for you.